# Is raw meat or raw vegetables easier for humans to digest?

Tags: cell-membrane, digestive-system, digestion

Which one is easier for a human digestive system to digest, raw meat or raw vegetables?

I have heard some of my friends who say that raw (or uncooked) meat is easier to digest than raw (or uncooked) vegetables.
It initially sounds absurd to me but then they back their argument with something more logical like, "raw vegetables have cells surrounded by rigid cell walls made primarily out of cellulose which are hard to break by the digestive enzymes".
Are they correct?
Anyway, for simplicity, let's assume on a fine day, a healthy adult eats 50g of raw beef and on another fine day she eats 50g of raw broccoli. Which of the two will she digest faster, provided she didn't eat anything else apart from these foods on those particular days.

**My Own Investigation**  I tried googling a lot but couldn't find anything that explicitly or even implicitly address my question. Most of the sites (like this [one](https://www.healthline.com/nutrition/raw-food-vs-cooked-food#TOC_TITLE_HDR_2)) address "raw food vs cooked food" type questions. However, all of a sudden, I remembered something that I studied almost two years back in my secondary school, class 10th science textbook. I quote the paragraph here,

[image: NCERT class 10th science textbook]

Access the full chapter here ([NCERT Class 10th Science Textbook](https://www.philoid.com/epub/ncert/10/154/jesc106?utm=com.ncert.chapter)) and check out 7th line (from top) of the 8th page.

This source further support their (my friends') claim in some manner.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "*easier*." Easier as in more mass breakdown, greater absorbing of nutrients, less indigestion,...?

Comment: also which vegetable,  all meat is more or less the the same but vegetable covers a huge range of tissue compositions. also almost all herbivores can digest meat, they have to be able to to reabsorb their own dead cells.

Comment: it will be wrong to compare human digestion with animals that eat grass(cellulose)and it is not very helpful to compare human digestion with other animals that eat the same diet as us.

Comment: @theforestecologist by easier I mean, which one (of equal mass) of the two undergo faster breakdown. And as far as vegetables are concerned, considered a typical mixture of green vegetables that we eat, e.g. cauliflower, cabbage, lettuce, broccoli, etc.

Comment: @GauravKumar You should focus on **one** vegetable. Knowing how well a mix of random vegetables will digest is basically impossible. Maybe stick to comparing broccoli and beef, for example.

Comment: @user438383 fine, let's stick to beef and broccoli!